# Debugging Node addons with CLion

Tags: c++, node.js, clion

I try to get my hands on [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql), a binding to MariaDB's C++ client library. For better understanding, I would like to debug the C++ part on Debian, using [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion).

Now, node-mariasql uses node-gyp as a build automation tool, whereas CLion only supports CMake, but is it still possible to debug a program ? I used CLion's JavaScript debugger to step into the JavaScript client, but of course when I reach a point where the C++ addon is called ([here](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/blob/master/lib/Client.js#L34) for instance), I cannot see what it is doing since the C++ debugging is not setup.

What are my options here ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's not possible, at this moment, or i just couldn't find solution.
We should wait until Jetbrains will add possibility attach debugger to process (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1001).
You can take a look to this tutorial: http://skitr.com/2014/05/13/debugging-node-js-addons-on-linux-and-mac-osx/, or use windows + visual studio, if you can (
http://computer-vision-talks.com/articles/how-to-debug-nodejs-addons-in-visual-studio/)

Comment: Attaching debugger to process is fixed in CLion EAP 1.5 : http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/01/attach-to-local-process/